# How to search and copy surrounding text?

Tags: shell, search, grep, full-text-search

I have a large textfile structured like this:

```
---

NAME: Some Name

Random
number
of lines with info.

---

NAME: Another Name

Random
number
of lines
with different info.

---

…
```

When searching for "different", I want to edit everything from "NAME: Another name" to "---" in a new file.

There may be multiple occurences of a search term. I would love to have all of them in one file.

`grep different file.txt > edit.txt` puts lines containing "different" in a new file.

But I don´t know how to do the same with everything between the two "---".

Is grep the right tool for the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` is the wrong tool for the job. Using GNU `awk` for multi-char RS and RT:

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)---(\n|$)' -v ORS= '/different/{print $0 RT}' file
```

For example given this input:

```
$ cat file
---

NAME: Some Name

Random
number
of lines with info.

---

NAME: Another Name

Random
different number ---
of lines

NAME: just part of some random text

with different info.

---

NAME: Yet another Name

Random
number
of lines
with different info.

---
```

the above command produces the expected output:

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)---(\n|$)' -v ORS= '/different/{print $0 RT}' file

NAME: Another Name

Random
different number ---
of lines

NAME: just part of some random text

with different info.

---

NAME: Yet another Name

Random
number
of lines
with different info.

---
```

while the awk command from [the OPs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77627851/1745001) outputs:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { RS = "---" } /different/' file


NAME: Another Name

Random
different number

of lines

NAME: just part of some random text

with different info.




NAME: Yet another Name

Random
number
of lines
with different info.
```

with the `---` from the middle of the second record replaced by a newline and all separator `---` lines gone so the `NAME:..` line from the middle of the second record cant be distinguished from other records, etc.

Comment: As Ed mentions, this is for GNU awk. Standard awk solutions do not allow `RS` to be a regular expression or multi-character expression.

Comment: Thank you for your addition! In my case the shorter command solves my problem. But I chose your answer over mine, since it is generally more applicable.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having a similar issue: awk solved this problem for me.

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "---" } /searchterm/' input.txt > edit.txt
```

Have a beautiful day!

Comment: That would corrupt input that had `---` mid-record and won't reproduce the `---` separator lines in the output.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, you are right. Gladly my file does not contain --- mid-record. But if it did, that would not work.